# Como buscar registros do mês anterior?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso pegar os dados do dia 01 ao dia 30 do mes anterior,  estou usando esta sintaxe. alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
SELECT SUM(DIFERENÇA)as Mesanterior
  FROM TOTALIZADOR
 WHERE NID = 252
   AND DATAHORA BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-1,DATEADD(DD,-DAY(GETDATE())+1,GETDATE()))
   AND DATEADD(DD,-DAY(GETDATE()),GETDATE())
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Select de meses anteriores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320869/select-de-meses-anteriores)

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

No **SQL Server 2008** você pode fazer algo assim:

```
SELECT
    SUM(DIFERENÇA) AS Mesanterior
FROM
    TOTALIZADOR
WHERE
    NID = 252 AND
    DATAHORA BETWEEN
        DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
    AND
        DATEADD(s,1,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)));
```

Recupera a data do primeiro dia do mês passado:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0));
```

Recupera a data do ultimo dia do mês passado:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,1,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)));
```

Se o seu servidor for igual ou superior ao **SQL Server 2012**, você pode usar a facilidade da função `EOMONTH()` para se obter o último dia do mês:

```
SELECT
    SUM(DIFERENÇA) AS Mesanterior
FROM
    TOTALIZADOR
WHERE
    NID = 252 AND
    DATAHORA BETWEEN
        DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2))
    AND
        EOMONTH( GETDATE(), -1 );
```

Recupera a data do primeiro dia do mês passado:

```
SELECT DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2));
```

Recupera a data do ultimo dia do mês passado:

```
SELECT EOMONTH( GETDATE(), -1 );
```

Referência:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql

Comment: deeu que EOMONTH não é uma função reconhecida

Comment: Olha só o meu teste no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/170/0

Comment: `EOMONTH` só se aplica a `SQL Server 2012` ou superior

Comment: @RonaldoSantos qual é a versão do seu servidor ?

Comment: @Lacobus a solução que você deu para o SQL Server 2008 é idêntica a que eu sugeri. Não é muito legal copiar uma resposta.

Comment: @Sorack Acho que você está enganado. Olhe bem! Não usei `DATEPART` na minha solução.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte sintaxe no seu `WHERE`:

```
SELECT SUM(DIFERENÇA) AS mesanterior
  FROM TOTALIZADOR
 WHERE NID = 252 
   AND DATEPART(MONTH, datahora) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
   AND DATEPART(YEAR, datahora) = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()));
```

---

> [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna uma data especificada com o intervalo numérico especificado (inteiro assinado) adicionado à parte da data especificada.

---

> [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174420(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna um inteiro que representa a parte da data especificada.

---

Em detalhes:

- `DATEPART(MONTH, datahora)` irá obter o mês do registro;
- `DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate()))` irá obter o mês anterior para comparação;
- `DATEPART(YEAR, datahora)` irá obter o ano do registro;
- `DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate()))` irá obter o ano do mês anterior para comparação;
- Dessa forma será comparado se o registro tem o mês `06/2017` no caso do exemplo.

---

**Observação:** Dessa forma será verificado se o mês e ano são equivalentes, portanto irá comparar os dias **31** dos meses com mais dias (janeiro, março, maio, julho, agosto, outubro e dezembro) e **28/29** de fevereiro.

Comment: eu fiz assim  " Select SUM(DIFERENÇA)as Mesanterior from TOTALIZADOR WHERE NID = 252 and DATAHORA between DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm,0,GetDate()) - 1, 0) AND DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm,0,GetDate()), -1) ";

Comment: @RonaldoSantos não entendo o porquê do uso do `DATEDIFF`. Se você utilizou a resposta, marque-a como escolhida para que alguém com dúvida similar possa se beneficiar também.