# Select de meses anteriores

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Preciso fazer `select` em dados dos meses anteriores, mês por mês.

Minha *query* está assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_INCD
 WHERE MONTH(DH_CRIA_INCD) = DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()) - 1
   AND YEAR(DH_CRIA_INCD) = YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Dá certo, faço select apenas do mês anterior, e se preciso ver o anterior do anterior, eu vou colocando "**- 2**", "**- 3**", etc...

O problema está quando preciso ver de dezembro, pois o ano muda e a consulta não retorna nada.
Como faço para que o ano acompanhe esse subtração de meses?

Comment: Você precisa ver todas as datas inferiores a data atual começando pelo mês anterior?

Comment: todos os meses anteriores da data atual, uma query por mês

Comment: Se você precisa informar a quantidade de subtração toda vez, não é mais fácil informar logo a data que deseja consultar no caso o mês/ano? Não consegui entender muito bem o porque está dessa forma, isso está em uma Procedure?  A consulta é sempre feita diretamente no banco de dados ?

Comment: Eu to montando um dashboard em PHP, que mostra em uma table a quantidade de problemas do mês atual (já fiz), e até 4 meses anteriores. Sim, diretamente do banco.

Comment: O problema é que a query que fiz, só adianta se for no mesmo ano, se uma pessoa for usar o dashboard em janeiro do ano que vem por exemplo, só vai conseguir ver o mês atual, e os 4 meses anteriores vai estar zerado pois o ano é diferente

Comment: OBS: é mês por mês, quantidade do mês atual: x, quantidade do mês anterior: x, etc..

Comment: Então existe uma limitação de no máximo 4 meses atrás? (pergunto isso, porque essas informações são relevantes para formar uma  solução).

Comment: Para esse dashboard sim, vai mostrar sempre a quantidade de problemas do mês atual, até 4 meses anteriores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem simples usando DATEFROMPARTS:

No **WHERE**:

`Parte esquerda`: estamos transformando a data atual no primeiro dia do mês e descolocando ele o número "@par" de vezes.

`Parte direita`: transformando a data da coluna no primeiro dia do mês.

E comparamos os 2 :)

Basta substituir @par pelo número de meses: -1, -2...

`SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_INCD
 WHERE dateadd(month, @par, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DH_CRIA_INCD), MONTH(DH_CRIA_INCD), 1)`

Comment: Eu tenho 13 problemas no mês anterior, essa query me retornou 6874 registros quando coloco -1 rsrsrsr

Comment: Que estranho, qual o formato de sua tabela? Aqui eu uso tranquilo. Deixa eu ver se fiz algum typo.

Comment: Execute assim, vê se as comparações estão fazendo sentido (as do mês que você quer tem que ter as duas colunas iguais): SELECT top(100)
    dateadd(month, @par, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) as left,
       DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DH_CRIA_INCD), MONTH(DH_CRIA_INCD), 1) as right
  FROM VIEW_INCD
  order by DH_CRIA_INCD desc

Answer (score 2):

Para obter os dados de somente um mês, experimente

```
-- código #1
-- informe número de meses a retroagir
declare @RetroMes tinyint;
set @RetroMes= 1;

-- calcula período mensal de consulta
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, current_timestamp) - @RetroMes, 0);
set @DataFinal= dateadd(month, +1, @DataInicial); 

--
SELECT colunas
  from VIEW_INCD
  where DH_CRIA_INCD >= @DataInicial 
        and DH_CRIA_INCD < @DataFinal;
```

Não testei; espero que não tenha erros.

---

Se quiser que em uma única consulta retorne todo o período, experimente o seguinte código:

```
-- código #2
-- informe número de meses do período
declare @RetroMes tinyint;
set @RetroMes= 4;

-- calcula período mensal de consulta
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataFinal= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, current_timestamp), 0);
set @DataInicial= dateadd(month, -@RetroMes, @DataFinal);

--
SELECT year(DH_CRIA_INCD) as Ano, 
       month(DH_CRIA_INCD) as Mês,
       colunas
  from VIEW_INCD
  where DH_CRIA_INCD >= @DataInicial 
        and DH_CRIA_INCD < @DataFinal;
```

Comment: Aí no PHP eu colocaria tudo isso na variável $query?

Comment: Como to buscando os dados com PHP, é possível usar declare e/ou set?

Answer (score 2):

Precisamos filtrar os últimos 4 meses (conforme seus comentários) a partir do mês atual do sistema.

Utilizamos a função **DATEADD(MONTH, -4, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))** para subtrairmos 4 meses da nossa data atual e usamos o **CONVERT(date, GETDATE())** para ignorarmos o horário.
**Observação:** Caso queira considerar o horário troque o **CONVERT(date, GETDATE())** por **GETDATE()**. Se precisar mudar a quantidade de meses para os últimos 5, 6, 7... meses altere o parâmetro **-4** para a quantidade de dias (de forma negativa, pois estamos subtraindo os meses) desejada **-5, -6, -7**.

Utilizamos a função **DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))** para ignorarmos o mês atual.

```
SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_INCD
 WHERE DH_CRIA_INCD BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -4, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
 ORDER BY DH_CRIA_INCD DESC
```

Para executar uma query apenas para 1 mês igual você disse nos comentários, tente executar o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_INCD
 WHERE DH_CRIA_INCD BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
   AND DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
 ORDER BY DH_CRIA_INCD DESC
```

A primeira parte do **BETWEEN** estamos passando o primeiro dia do mês anterior (por causa do -1).

**Observação:** Caso queira mudar o mês adicione -1, -2, -3 após a função DATEADD, porém o -1 se refere a 1 mes anterior, o -2 se refere a 2 meses anteriores, e assim por diante.

**Exemplo:** Considerando que o GETDATE() retornará o dia 08/08/2018, a função abaixo irá retornar 01/07/2018.

```
 DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
```

A segunda parte do **BETWEEN** estamos passando o último dia do mês anterior.

**Observação:** Caso queira mudar o mês adicione -1, -2, -3 após a função DATEADD, porém o -1 se refere a 2 meses anteriores, o -2 se refere a 3 meses anteriores, e assim por diante.
**Exemplo:** Considerando que o GETDATE() retornará o dia 08/08/2018, a função abaixo irá retornar 30/06/2018.

```
DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
```

Comment: Acompanha o ano? Se eu executar essa Query em Janeiro ele busca os meses anteriores do ano anterior? E tbm não posso fazer uma query para todos os meses, disse que é mês por mês

Comment: Acompanha o ano sim, se você informar por exemplo 01/01/2018 e pedir -4 meses, irá te retornar até o mês 09 de 2017. Como assim uma query de mês por mês? Não entendi.

Comment: Uma query que volte apenas os dados de um mês, independente se é o mês anterior, ou 2 meses atrás. O mês que devera mostrar, vai ser definido na query

Comment: Alterei a resposta incluindo também a "query mês por mês", vou aqui também um link de outra pergunta em que explico sobre como buscar o último dia do mês. Link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319818/sql-atualizando-valor-errado/319829#319829

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria a subtração da data no php e passaria para o banco o mês e ano de consulta desejado, preferencialmente em uma Procedure.

Como alternativa fiz uma consulta baseada na sua que te permitirá obter o resultado desejado, vale ressaltar que esta solução está limitada a quatro meses que é sua necessidade.

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo:](http://SELECT%20*%20%20FROM%20VIEW_INCD%20WHERE%20%20%20%20MONTH(DH_CRIA_INCD)%20=%20%20%20%20CASE%20DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())%20-8%20%20%20%20%20WHEN%200%20%20THEN%2012%20%20%20%20%20WHEN%20-1%20THEN%2011%20%20%20%20%20WHEN%20-2%20THEN%2010%20%20%20%20%20WHEN%20-3%20THEN%209%20%20%20ELSE%20%20%20%20%20DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())%20-%208%20%20%20END%20AND%20%20%20%20YEAR(DH_CRIA_INCD)%20=%20%20%20CASE%20WHEN%20DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())%20-%208%20%3C%201%20THEN%20%20%20%20%20YEAR(GETDATE())%20-%201%20%20%20ELSE%20%20%20%20%20YEAR(GETDATE())%20%20%20END)

```
SELECT * 
FROM VIEW_INCD
WHERE 
  MONTH(DH_CRIA_INCD) = 
  CASE DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()) -8
    WHEN 0  THEN 12
    WHEN -1 THEN 11
    WHEN -2 THEN 10
    WHEN -3 THEN 9
  ELSE
    DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()) - 8
  END
AND 
  YEAR(DH_CRIA_INCD) =
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()) - 8 < 1 THEN
    YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
  ELSE
    YEAR(GETDATE())
  END
```